# sql call 2 times the same key_name in the same request key by 2 different ways

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

the db has 2 tables names trip and user.
[image: 1]

### trip

id      | description | user_id |

(user_id references user(id)) (this foreign key means the creator of the trip)

### user

id    | username

the user could be a participant too, so there is an association table with user_id (references user(id) as participant) and trip_id (references to trip(id), this is the trip which is participating the user participant. [a user can participate to many trips and a trip can have many particpants].
so i want to get in a request postgresql the trip with the user created the trip and all the user who are participating to this trip.
i don't find th way to obtain all the participants. any solution is welcome, thanks !

Comment: Some example data would help here. Is user_id being used to store the trip creator and the participants? Could you post your attempt please?

Comment: i have adding the MCD upper. 
in the table trip, user_id references the user as creator (there is always only one creator for a trip), but a trip could have many participants so the relation named "participate"  associates user_id (as participant) and the trip id. So a trip_id can be associated with many user_id and a user_id can be associated to many trips, that's why there is an association table with these 2 foreign keys (user_id and trip_id).

How to obtain this result if trip with id=1 is asked :
[
trip:
{ id: 1}
creator: 
{user_id: 1}
participant :
{user_id: 2,
user_id: 3
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically just a select from the M:M resolution table to each parent. The twist is you also need to retrieve the 1:M from user to trip. Since the user in each may be different you require 2 references to the users table. One to retrieve the participant and one to retrieve the who created the trip. So: see [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3cd62882fdac4c88d15e77897b156846).

```
select t.description "Description"
     , ut.username   "Organized by"
     , up.username   "Participant" 
  from participants  p
  join trips  t  on (t.trip_id  = p.trip_id)
  join users  ut on (ut.user_id = t.created_by)
  join users  up on (up.user_id = p.participant_id);
```